# Creating a custom column

Tags: column, promoted-links

Trying to create a 2 column section at the beginning of the page as shown in the image below - basically 2 column at the top but then rest as one column. One column will have an image and the other will have promoted links. Any (relatively easy) way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: How? What? Where? Do you want this in a content placeholder? A page layout? Master page? Custom webpart? SPFx webpart? ......

Answer (score 0):

You can use `colspan` as below

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src=""/></td>
        <td><h2>Promoted Links</h2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```